# HAproxy features

Tags: haproxy

will anyone tell me how HAproxy actually works.i searched alot but i want a simple and easy explaination about overall HAproxy.

Answer (score 2):

HAProxy is commonly used for load balancing, ie. you have a number of web servers and you wanted to distribute requests between them and seamlessly handle things like when a server goes down.

Configure HAProxy in front, and it'll forward connections (hence, it is a proxy) in such a way that connections will be spread between servers.

In practice, there are tons of configuration and complexities to fit specific needs.  I'd start by taking a look at the [docs](http://code.google.com/p/haproxy-docs/).  [Here](http://code.google.com/p/haproxy-docs/wiki/Configuring#Examples) is an example of HAProxy being used as, well, a proxy to forward http connections.  If you add more servers it'll load balance between those servers.  There are more examples spread out through the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

It's not very clear what you're looking for. Haproxy does many different things so there's no single response. I suggest you take a look at the architecture manual. It's quite old but will give you some concrete examples of what you can do with it.

Comment: first time i am using linux machine and want to configure haproxy in linux fedora. will you please prove me some link that help me to do it easily....I want step by step documentation....